# How do I go about separating participants' data when it's all together?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataset that has responses from 90 different people. I want to get the mean of the reaction time for each participant. The thing is, the data is all together and the participants are only separated by a few lines. How do I separate it so that I can analyze the individual data and then proceed to analyze the whole data?

This is how one participant's answers look (there are a lot more lines for each person but I made it shorter here):

```
resultstime,ipaddress,controller,numberitem,innernumber,label,latingp,penntype,pennname,parameter,value,eventime,word,color,correct,rt,comment2                                                     
# Results on Sunday May 02 2021 02:27:05 UTC                                                            
# USER AGENT:                                                       
# Design number was non-random = 37                                                         
#                                                           
# Columns below this comment are as follows:                                                            
# 1. Results reception time.                                                            
# 2. MD5 hash of participant's IP address.                                                          
# 3. Controller name.                                                           
# 4. Order number of item.                                                          
# 5. Inner element number.                                                          
# 6. Label.                                                         
# 7. Latin Square Group.                                                            
# 8. PennElementType.                                                           
# 9. PennElementName.                                                           
# 10. Parameter.                                                            
# 11. Value.                                                            
# 12. EventTime.                                                            
# 13. Comments.                                                         
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,0,0,instructions,NULL,PennController,0,_Trial_,Start,1619922251848,NULL                                                          
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,0,0,instructions,NULL,PennController,0,_Trial_,End,1619922268551,NULL                                                            
# 13. word.                                                         
# 14. color.                                                            
# 15. correct.                                                          
# 16. Comments.                                                         
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,3,0,experimental-trial2,NULL,PennController,5,_Trial_,Start,1619922268565,AVIÓN, green, v,NULL                                                           
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,3,0,experimental-trial2,NULL,Text,word,Print,NA,1619922268568,AVIÓN, green, v,NULL                                                           
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,3,0,experimental-trial2,NULL,Key,keypress,PressedKey,A,1619922271453,AVIÓN, green, v,Wait success
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,7,0,experimental-trial2,NULL,PennController,9,_Trial_,End,1619922289638,FLOR, red, r,NULL                                                            
# 13. Comments.                                                         
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,10,0,instructions2,NULL,PennController,1,_Trial_,Start,1619922289645,NULL                                                            
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,10,0,instructions2,NULL,PennController,1,_Trial_,End,1619922296059,NULL                                                          
# 13. word.                                                         
# 14. color.                                                            
# 15. correct.                                                          
# 16. RTword.                                                           
# 17. Comments.                                                         
1619922425,5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c,PennController,55,0,experimental-trial,NULL,PennController,56,_Trial_,Start,1619922296066,CASA, red, r,1230,NULL
```

So basically this type of code is repeated 90 times. Maybe I could separate it by the line # Results, since that's when the response begins, but how would I go around doing that?

Comment: These columns appear to be standard for the first 12 and then change for 13 and following. Which columns do you care about? If its just a few things in the first 12 columns, then this is mostly an exercise in discarding stuff. You want the mean of the reaction time... which column is that?

Comment: I added the header with the name of the columns but the thing is, the column are all important, even if the reaction time is the one I have to focus on. I just don't know how I can detect the rows that belong to a person and then to another person. They are separated by the row that says "Results on.." by how do I go about doing that?

Comment: You header only matches the last line.  Seems like the format of each set of lines is continually being redefined via the # lines.  Does not stay the same.  What is the data you want to capture?  What would your output look like?  Looks like a Start-End set of lines constitutes some kind of interaction by the user.  Do want to capture all of these?  Or some kind of summary or some specifically extracted data ?

Comment: @jch Yes, my header matches the last line and those are the ones I want to grab. I have already written a code to do that but my issue is that that code is good to analyze the whole data but I would also need to separate it by person. The different responses are separated by the "Results on.." row. Basically, what I am showing is just One response but they are all together and only separated by the row I mentioned before. I just don't know how to separate the amount of rows that belong to each person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the code below:

```
import re
import csv
import io

person = ['Person ID']

common = ["Results reception time", "MD5 hash of participant's IP address", 
          "Controller name", "Order number of item", "Inner element number",
          "Label", "Latin Square Group", "PennElementType", "PennElementName",
          "Parameter", "Value", "EventTime"]

extra = ["word", "color", "correct", "RTword", "Comments"]

fields = person + common + extra

is_last_data = True
person_id = 0
data = []

for line in open('data.csv').readlines():
    # New person
    if line.startswith('# Results on'):
        person_id += 1

    # Metadata (order of extra fields)
    elif line.startswith('#'):
        sre = re.match(r'# 1[3-7]\. (\w+)\.', line)
        if sre:
            if is_last_data == True:
                extra = []
                is_last_data = False
            extra.append(sre.group(1))

    # Data (new response)
    else:
        d = next(csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(line),
                                fieldnames=person+common+extra))
        d['Person ID'] = person_id
        data.append(d)
        is_last_data = True


# Dump data as csv
with open('compile.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data)

df = pd.read_csv('compile.csv')
```

```
>>> df
   Person ID            Results reception time MD5 hash of participant's IP address  Controller name  Order number of item  ...    word  color       correct RTword Comments
0          1  5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c                       PennController                0                     0  ...     NaN    NaN           NaN    NaN      NaN
1          1  5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c                       PennController                0                     0  ...     NaN    NaN           NaN    NaN      NaN
2          1  5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c                       PennController                3                     0  ...   green      v           NaN    NaN      NaN
3          1  5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c                       PennController                3                     0  ...   green      v           NaN    NaN      NaN
4          1  5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c                       PennController                3                     0  ...   green      v  Wait success    NaN      NaN
5          1  5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c                       PennController                7                     0  ...     red      r           NaN    NaN      NaN
6          1  5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c                       PennController               10                     0  ...     NaN    NaN           NaN    NaN      NaN
7          1  5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c                       PennController               10                     0  ...     NaN    NaN           NaN    NaN      NaN
8          1  5fe43773223070f515613ba23f3b770c                       PennController               55                     0  ...     red      r          1230    NaN      NaN
```